# Can the deploy-token access the history commit in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

As the title .
The deploy-token in gitlab can have a read_repository permission.

## Is it possible to access history commit of a repository by a deploy-token?

Comment: If you can read the repo you can clone it.

Comment: Does the **clone action** also clones the history commits ?

Comment: This is git we're talking about. There is nothing but the history of actions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I think the clone command can only copy the code data from git.

Comment: When you do `git clone` you copy the entire history of the branch pointed at by `HEAD` on the remote. . https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone

Comment: many thanks for this answer .@BoristheSpider